# Creating a GIF using gif.js does not work with transparent images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm using [gif.js](https://github.com/jnordberg/gif.js) to create a GIF maker for a popular online game but I am having issues with the images not being transparent.

Here is how it should look (Minus the black background)

[image: sprite]

Here is how it currently looks. Notice how the black lines are transparent aswell, I want to avoid that and just have the background transparent

[image: sprite]

Here's where I create the gif instance (Or see [full code here](https://pastebin.com/dPEpmQFD))

```
function getGifInstance()
{
    return new GIF({
        workers: 2,
        workerScript: BASE_URL + '/libs/gifjs/dist/gif.worker.js',
        quality: 10,
        width: 64,
        height: 110,
        transparent: '#000'
    });
}
```

Comment: Change the background to a colour that isn't used in the image.  You're telling it that black should become transparent, so it is.

Comment: @Archer I've tried changing the background and transparent color to '#D4A190' but it's still like the second image. Not sure why

Comment: So you opened the gif in a graphics package and painted the background a different colour, but left all the black lines that you want to stay in the finished image?

Comment: @Archer  what are you on about?

Comment: You're telling it that black should be the transparent colour, so *all* black will become transparent.

Answer (score 1):

"Minus the black background" is the crucial part of your question. If that's what your source file looks like, then there's not a lot you can do, because you're using the same color for the background *and* for the artwork.

You need your input to have a truly transparent background or a [chroma key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) color (magenta is commonly used as a chroma key color in software and video games).